# How do I perform a mixed regression model with a ‘bias’ associated to each variable?

Tags: mixed-model

I have a mock dataset on cheese intake which shows the intake of cheese (in g, Continuous), the disease type (Categorical), the outcome (Categorical) and the Evidence quality (Categorical, 0 to 3 where higher is better).

```
Qty Disease Outcome E.quality
20  Migraine    Positive    0
30  Heartburn       Negative    3
10  Migraine    Positve 1
5   Heartburn   Neutral 2
20  Migraine    Positive    2
2   Lipidema    Positive    1
40  Lipidema    Negative    3
20  Heartburn       Positive    1
```

I wish to build a model such that for a given `Disease` type, the quantity of cheese consumption (`qty`) must be optimized to get a positive `Outcome`. The evidence quality (`E.quality`) here serves as the bias for the evidence.

The default code without any bias is:

```
lm(data=df, formula= Qty~Disease+Outcome)
```

How to account for bias in this equation? How do I perform this in R?

Comment: What form do you think the "bias" has? Is it more uncertainty that grows about the quantity of cheese or the outcome? Or more systematic biases (e.g. selection bias in the data) that can go in any direction (but may consistently go one way for some disease)? If you can write down a data generating process to approx. describe how data arises, you can use it as the likelihood in a model. Wouldn't you want to model the outcome? `Qty ~ Disease + Outcome` would be more suitable for a randomized trial where you assign people to have a outcome and see how much cheese people eat as a result.

Comment: @Björn : The `E.Quality` is a scoring on how strong the evidence is for the claimed outcome. I expect that this bias would affect the overall y-intercept of the regression model. How do I incorporate that? I also wanted the equation so I can substitute the coefficients for `Positive` and make that `1` and make the others `0` so I can get the corresponding cheese `Qty` of interest.